# É possivel abrir um link em uma aba especifica do navegador usando algum target=""?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, link

Tenho um sisteminha de cadastro de contatos com um botão para mandar mensagem de whatsapp pelo whatsappweb.

Quando clico nesse botão, ele abre uma aba do whatsappweb na conversa com esse contato:

```
<a href="https://wa.me/55'.$telefone.'" target="_blank">Mandar WhatsApp</a>
```

Só que sempre que clico ele abre em uma nova aba por causa do target="_blank".

Tem como ao clicar, ele abrir esse link na aba em que o whatsappweb já está aberta? Pois como o whatsappweb só permite 1 aba aberta, sempre que clico em alguma conversa, tenho que ir fechar a outra aba já aberta do whatsapp.

Pode usar php, javascript, jquery.

Comment: Não deu pra entender direito a sua pergunta, este botão está no seu sistema ou no whatsappweb? Caso seja no seu sistema basta remover o atributo target que ele irá abrir o conteúdo na mesma aba.

Comment: Acho que você quer usar o framename ele vai sempre atualizar a pagina aberta pelo link

Comment: dei uma olhada em framename, pelo que entendi eu teria que criar um frame dentro do meu sistema, e linkar pra dentro dele certo?

Comment: @SerenoMendes o botão fica dentro do meu sistema, não quero abrir na mesma aba, quero abrir na aba que já está aberta "whatsapp"